# Visual Studio Web Form: couple questions

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, webforms

I'm trying to create a simple web form with some basic validation. I've had some basic .NET courses, but it's been quite a while, so bear with me please:

- What's the most efficient way to store / manipulate the data that has
  been entered by users? Should I stick to the MVC model no matter what, even for
  something fairly simple?
- I want to make use of autocomplete on certain fields. These fields gather information from a certain database. There seem to be **a lot**
  of    opinions on this one! What should I really go with? JSON, JQuery, JS, 
  AJAX?
- What's the best practice when it comes to validation? It seems like I
  should start out with server side validation and worry    about 
  client    side validation later? As of now I just have a "asp:RequiredFieldValidator" tag embedded in my .aspx page..
- I'm using the lastest version of Visual Studio which seems to
  incorporated Bootstrap. I'm also using a Master page so I can have a consistent layout across multiple pages. However, When I include the form div tags (which are mentioned in the bootstrap.css file) together with the BodyContent tags, the layout seems very skewed. I've resorted to the built-in ASP UI elements (e.g. asp:TextBox) and the html table tags. Is there any way I can have the best of both worlds and combine the Master/BodyContent layout together with the bootstrap form layout?

Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a resource for asking for fully designed solutions.  If in the course of coding your described problem, you have specific questions, feel free to add them here, but asking for a fully designed solution is not a question accepted under guidelines.

Comment: MVC and Web Forms are not the same thing - they are two very different approaches to creating web sites.   **Always** do validation on *both* the client-side and server-side (in case the user disables JS in the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I'd recommend you to stick with regular MVC practices no matter how simple is your task. Unless you need to develop Single-Page-Application which is a little different approach.

For autocomplete you can still use ASP.NET MVC for Ajax calls or introduce Web API controller. Web API is designed for building RESTful services. MVC version of your action would look like that:

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string query)
{
    var autocompleteValues = autocompleteService.GetValues(query)
    return Json(autocompleteValues , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'd recommend to use `jQuery` for client-side coding. It's simple, flexible and cross-browser.

Use unobtrusive ASP.NET MVC validation. With this approach you will get client-side and server-side validation right away. Make sure, you have following libraries linked:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Check your configuration. These two guys should be enabled:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

---

The question is too broad. If you don't know how to start, check http://asp.net/mvc website for tutorials and take a look at Visual Studio MVC template project. You will find a lot of basic concept examples in it.